# How to extend 2 classes?

Tags: android, service, listactivity, extend

This might be a silly question, but I'm struggling on how to make my class extend 2 classes at the same time. I'm trying to make a SERVICE that uses ListActivity. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are coding in the `Java programming language`. Then the simple answer is: You don't. Java does not support deriving from multiple classes.
Make your `ListActivity` contain a `Service`.

```
class MyService extends Service{
  ...
}

class MyList extends ListActivity{
    MyService service = new MyService();
}
```

Comment: How do I do that without extending a service?

Comment: @user1102714 I added an example

Answer (score 1):

Java or android Doesn't Support `Multiple Inheritance`

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can't extend more than 1 class at the same time. However, you can implement more than 1 interface (but this is not about your task).

You should look for [bound service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. You may need to re-architect your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can never actually extend 2 classes directly, you need to use a few tricks and make a few interfaces to get it to work. Here is a guide: http://csis.pace.edu/~bergin/patterns/multipleinheritance.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean [this kind of Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html), you cannot do this at all; irrespective of Java's lack of multiple inheritance. Services cannot also be Activities. You should create a Service, and a separate ListActivity, and [use a binder to communicate between them](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html).

When you do want to inherit the functionality of two classes, use the [delegation pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern).